# How to match nested option values in scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

```
 let x = new Row(job_id="hello", title=null)

 x match {
     case Row(
           job_id: String,
           title: Option[String]) => println("successful match")
     case _ => println("failed!")

}
```

For the code above when I try to match with an option type it actually matches with `_` and gives me a warning shown below:

```
warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern Option[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

Basically the Row struct represents a sql row with nullable values and I want to be able to pattern match to it. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Where is Row defined? Also, I think you want None, not null.

Comment: It is not possible if you work with `Row`, because `Row` works with raw values, which include `null`s for absent values.

Comment: Row comes from spark so it's actually a null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use type patterns (`: String` and `: Option[String]`), because `null` doesn't match them. Write

```
case Row(job_id, title) =>
```

and check inside.

(When you get a `Row` from Spark, it won't contain any `Option[String]`s anyway, just null or non-null `String`s(/`Int`s/etc.).

You could also use custom [extractor objects](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112), e.g.

```
object OptString {
  def unapply(x: String) = Some(Option(x))
}
// repeat for other types
```

then

```
case Row(job_id, OptString(title)) =>
```

will bind `title` to `None` for your `x` and wouldn't match for

```
new Row("hello", notAString)
```